# Taking screenshot of dynamically opened windows form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I have the name of the form in variable and I need to show that form, take a screenshot of it, and convert it to bytes so i can save it in database.

My code is something like this:

```
 var form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(string.Format("namespace.{0}", FormName)), Parameter1, Parameter2);
 using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(form.Width, form.Height - 50))
 {
    form.Show();
    DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));

    byte[] bytes;
    using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
       bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
       bytes = stream.ToArray();
    }
    form.Close();
 }
```

The thing is, i get screenshot from the main form not from the child form i want ... Any ideas how i can achieve this?

Maybe this code should be inside the child form, but I don't know how to call a method dynamically from dynamic from.

Comment: Just forgot the `form.` in the `DrawToBitmap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dinamically handle the `FormClosed` `Event` of the form you want to screenshot. You pay special attention to `bounds`.

```
 Form f = new Form();
            f.FormClosed += (se, ev) => {
                Rectangle bounds = f.Bounds; //Important to set the bounds of the Form you want to screenshot
                using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
                {
                    using (Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                    {
                        graph.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                    }
                    bitmap.Save("screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
                }
            };
            f.Show();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            f.Close();
```

In this case I must wait for `2000 milisec`. to give enough time to the form to be painted. However you can handle other events. i.e. the click of a `button` inside the form.

Comment: I actually solved it with adding "form.DrawToBitmap..." instead of "DrawToBitmap". This is the form method that is getting the data from the from that it's called.